# Form fields are not saved into database - ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, form-submit

I have a form here https://pastebin.com/JfXr054y

In `routes.rb` I have

```
resources :landslides, only: [:new, :create, :index]
```

In `landslides_controller.rb` I have

```
  def new
    @landslide = Landslide.new(landslide_params)

    @landslide.save
    render plain: @landslide.inspect
  end
```

and

```
def landslide_params
  params.require(:landslide).permit(:total_id, :year_id, :start_date, :end_date, :day_number, :continent, :country, :location, :type, :admin_level, :new_lat, :new_long, :mapped, :spatial_area, :fatalities, :injuries, :notes, :sources)
end
```

Why the form isn't saved into the table?

Comment: Check the return value of save, maybe it's because of your model's validations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`new` is the wrong method in which to perform `#save`. that should be done in `create`

```
  def new
    @landslide = Landslide.new
  end

  def create
    @landslide = Landslide.new(landslide_params)
    if @landslide.save
      render plain: @landslide.inspect
    else
      render :new
    end
  end
```

Also, your form looks wrong.  The location of the form data in your returned params depends on the control's `name` field, not on the `id`

Instead of

```
%input#location.form-control{:type => "Location"}
```

I'd expect to see

```
%input#landslide_location.form-control{:type => "text", :name => "landslide[location]"}
```

Comment: I changed as yours and it still doesn't work. Something wrong with the form I think.

Comment: Here's my submit button `%button.btn.btn-default{"data-dismiss" => "modal", :type => "submit"} Submit`. Also do I need specific attribute for each field?

Comment: Yeah, you're right, your form is non-standard. See my edit.

Comment: It doesn't work though. The form is in views/index, is that a problem? Shouldn't it in views/landslide?

Comment: Yes, I was expecting you would have followed rails conventions.  Since you haven't, all bets are off.  I don't know what else about your application is wired strangely. Is there some reason you decided not to follow standard practice?